# how to scroll to different page section on tab press in flutter

Tags: flutter, scroll, tabs, tabbar

In my flutter app I have a tabbar and tabbarview. Currently when I switch from one tab to another, I am loading different pages. However, what I would like to do is scroll to another section in the main page instead of loading different page. How can we achieve this?
I have taken tabbar as base since that is what i am using in the app. If there is any other simpler approach to this, then also i am fine.

Comment: you're going to have to add some code of your current page

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `PageView` and treat each page as section.

Note: set `pageSnapping` to false for custom scroll behavior.

[Demo for sections in same screen](https://dartpad.dev/db28847d19e7aa11072aeeff3839c792)

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. What I want is basically when I tap on a tab in tabbar, I want to scroll down to a different section within the same page. Basically I just want to scroll up and down with each tap.

Comment: You can create your own widget.